# Menu drover effect when hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am creating a effect such that when u hover on  `.hoverarea` class then `.sociallink1`,`.sociallink2` and etc will be toggled like drover effect but my code is not working

And ther is also extra margin abhove each `.sociallink1` and etc are geeting added automaticaly when i  added only of `2px`

following is my code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sociallink1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.sociallink2 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.sociallink3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.sociallink4 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.sociallink5 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}

.hoverarea {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link1 {
  // position:relative;
  left: -200px;
}

.link2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
}

.link3 {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
}

.link4 {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
}

.link5 {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
}

.hoverarea:hover .link1 {
  // position:relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link1">

    <div class="sociallink1">Facebook </div>
    <div class="hoverarea">f</div>

  </div>
  <div class="link2">
    <div class="sociallink2">Google+ </div>
    <div class="hoverarea">G+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link3">
    <div class="sociallink3">Instagram </div>
    <div class="hoverarea">I</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link4">
    <div class="sociallink4">Pinterest </div>
    <div class="hoverarea">P</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link5">
    <div class="sociallink5">Twitter </div>
    <div class="hoverarea">T</div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the "property" that you want to transition, in your case `left`.
I also changed your code a bit, making it compacter.

When using classes, try to optimize it so that you don't have 5 different classes, but just one (or two).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}

.link {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  left: -200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.link>div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.link:hover {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    Facebook
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    Google+
    <div>G+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    Instagram
    <div>I</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    Pinterest
    <div>P</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    Twitter
    <div>T</div>
  </div>
</div>
```